# mod_rewrite messing up includes

Tags: html, css, mod-rewrite

I have the following mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^home/ home.php [L]
```

Fairly simple.
When I head to home.php, everything loads fine, but when I head to me.com/home/, the CSS doesn't load. CSS draws from

```
lib/css/home.css
```

which isn't in the same folder.. To clarify, my structure is:

```
/htdocs
home.php
/lib
    /css
        home.css
```

How can I solve this problem without rewriting my css's references?

Comment: Edit to show what your current references look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know if that will help to solve your problem, but i solved it using base href html tag, smth like

<   base href="http://www.domain.com" >

in head section makes all images, css and js files paths relative to www.domain.com

Comment: Note that changing the base URI will affect *every* relative URI and not just relative URI paths.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's why I have variable (let's say $sys_url), which holds URL to site (http://www.me.com/). When I want to load CSS, I type

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $sys_url; ?>lib/css/home.css" />`

Maybe this is nasty and better workaround exists, but it works for me :)